# Third party DLL reference in the C# project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, dll, reference

Below is my scenario :

I am working on a C# project and using a third party paid DLL. So, I added reference it in my project(Normally, put DLL in a separate folder and added "Add a reference"). 
Every year, I have to update this DLL with new DLL.(when I renew and paid for new one)

Problem : If I just update the DLL on the production server, it won't work. I have to update the DLL in my code and added a fresh reference and create a new build. So, I have to update all the code(new build) because of a SINGLE DLL.

Is there any way that I could update only required DLL, not all the code.

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [DependencyInjection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178469(v=pandp.30).aspx), might be a suitable approach for you

Comment: Please explain "it won't work"; is there an exception? Give some details about this DLL; is it a .NET/managed assembly or COM based?